# jQuery Event for all Button/Link Clicks or DropDown Changes on View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, preview

I'm working in asp.net mvc3 and have partial views for my tabs and log-in data. In one view (my preview view) I generate some images, and upload them to a cloud and then display them for the user. The user can then select `Cancel` or `Submit`.

I'd like to have any button, ActionLink, or dropdown besides `Submit` do the Cancel function (which involves deleting the images from the cloud, and some other things), but I'm not sure how to get a jQuery event handler for every event besides `Submit` click. Currently, I have a jQuery "Cancel" function that is bound to a click event on the `Cancel` button, and now need to expand its usage.

I figured this is self explanatory but if you need to see code, just ask.

**All Possible Events:**
In my partial views, I have these razor html helpers: 2 x `@Html.ActionLinks` and 1 x `@Html.DropDownList`

My Cancel and Submit buttons are of this form: `<input type="submit" value="Cancel" />`

**[UPDATE]:** I have my click event working now, however I would like to use `e.preventDefault();` on my clicks so it doesn't change views before my Cancel/delete finishes, but then how do I synchronously submit an item after my Cancel function finishes? I assume I use a callback, but do I use `e.submit()` or `e.click()` or something else? I would like it to work for `<a>` tags and `dropDown` changes

Comment: What types of buttons are they? <input type="button"> or <button>?

Comment: Sorry for forgetting that piece of information. I have updated my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
$("input,a,select").not("input:submit").click(function(e) {
    // do work
});
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/eqwkD/

---

**Update**

```
$("input,a,select").not("#SubmitButton").click(function(e) {
    // do work
});
```

Comment: Won't this try to do the function on any mouseclick or hover event?

Comment: this is catching click events on those elements and then removing the ones on submit buttons.

Comment: Ah that's cool. I was responding to your pre-edited version with `*:not` or something along those lines.

Comment: Is there someway to change the `.not("input:submit")` to something like this: `.attr('id')!="SubmitButton"` <-- That's the id of my submit input. My cancel input is type submit as well so your code would stop that from occurring too. I could have a separate jquery click event for that button but would like an all-in-one solution.

Answer (score 1):

The next code will call the cancelFunction upon click if it is not of type submit:

```
$(":input").click(function ({
    if (!$('#myinput').is(':submit')) {
         cancelFunction();
    }
});
```

This will make all buttons that are not of type submit call the cancel button. If you want to be more specific add an id to the button and use the following code:

```
$(":input").click(function() {
    if (!($('#myinput').attr("id") == "idOfSubmitButton")) {
         cancelFunction();
    }
})
```

Comment: This looks very promising. I will test it and then select your answer if it works :)

Comment: First of all, doing $(input) without quotes was incorrect I think, second you forgot the function inside of your `click()` --> `click(function() {`. This also, only seemed to work for my Cancel input, not for any inputs from my partial views. I do not know why though :(

Comment: I think if I added an "a" tag to the jquery selector it would work great for everything, however I found hunter's answer to be a bit more concise. +1 though!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the :not selector in your jQuery click handler:

```
$("input,a,select").not("#submit").click(cancelFunction);
```

This would select all input elements *except* for an element with id 'submit' and bind them to your cancel function.

Comment: Thanks but I edited my original post as my items are not of type "button"